# Can Filipino citizens get a visa upon arrival in South Korea?

Tags: visas, passports, south-korea, filipino-citizens

I'm a Filipino citizen, and I am in Macau. Can I get visa upon arrival in South Korea (Seoul)?

Answer (score 3):

Normally Philippines' citizens do not fall under visa exemption as described on [Korean Government site](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&showMenuId=375), however under [APEC Business Travel Card](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&showMenuId=375) you can enter Korea and receive a C-2 visa up to 90 days upon arrival.

Answer (score 2):

The Philippines is not amongst the [Countries under visa exemption agreement](http://www.mofat.go.kr/ENG/visa/application/) for ordinary people. Its citizens are, however, exempted of visa fees for short stay of no more than 59 days.

So, as far as I can tell, the answer to your question is **no**. You have to apply for a visa before coming to South Korea.

See also: [Wikipedia: Visa policy of South Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea)